# Playable audio formats with Apache Cordova Media Plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, apache-cordova

Does anyone know what are the audio formats that can be played by Apache Cordova Media plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media)?

Does the Apache Cordova Media plugin support the same formats as the Audio API (HTML5) would support? What if the Audio API is not supported? Will the Apache Cordova Media plugin still work? How to know or check the formats supported?

Thank you in advance,
 Joan

Answer (score 1):

The supported media formats are a function of the platform, not of Cordova. Cordova simply provides access to the underlying native platform, it does not replace those features. So the media encode and decode formats supported by the platform are those that you should expect to work with the Cordova APIs.

See this [Windows Phone quirk](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#windows-quirks) in the Media docs, for example. I have successfully used a WAV file on Android, iOS, Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 platforms. I can't vouch for other platforms.

To determine all your options, you'll need to check the native developers documentation for each platform to determine media encode and decode support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would need a method in JavaScript to check which formats are supported by the platform which is running the Cordova app. Would the canPlayType() method of the HTML5 Audio API tell me something useful about that? I am aware that the HTML5 Audio API and the Apache Cordova Media plugin are two different things but they run on the same platform after all. By the way, the link you provided does not go directly to the Windows Phone quirk you wanted to point.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the responses ("probably" and "maybe") from the canPlayType() method are of much value... If you see [this Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) it doesn't help much, other than to provide you with (hopefully) known minimum set of supported codecs. Simplest solution would be to assemble a table of known supported formats for the platforms you want to support and detect the platform using window.cordova.platformId

Comment: I could use cordova.platformId or device.platform to find out the platform which is running the app, but I would need to know what formats are supported by the different platforms and their versions, as for example the different versions of Windows Phone, Blackberry, iOS, etc. With that, I could make a (very big) table. But it seems too complicated. It is a pity if there is no other way to accomplish this.